# Magento 2.3.2 upgrade issues (category page, di compile, and cms pages)

Tags: magento2.3, cms-pages, magento-upgrade, category-page

Magento upgraded from 2.2.6 to 2.3.2, and there are issues:
- All category pages are having error,
"Undefined factory mysql".

> Exception #0 (DomainException): Undefined factory mysql

- Also di:compile command is having issue of temando shipping module (disabling it doesn't work).

> Fatal error:  Declaration of Temando\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\CollectionPoint\QuoteCollectionPointRepository::save(Temando\Shipping\Api\Data\CollectionPoint\QuoteCollectionPointInterface $collectionPoint) must be compatible with Temando\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Repository\QuoteCollectionPointRepositoryInterface::save(Temando\Shipping\Api\Data\Delivery\QuoteCollectionPointInterface $collectionPoint) in vendor/temando/module-shipping-m2/Model/ResourceModel/CollectionPoint/QuoteCollectionPointRepository.php on line 30

- And lastly all cms pages also having issue of page builder template

> Argument 2 passed to Magento\PageBuilder\Plugin\Filter\TemplatePlugin::afterFilter() must be of the type string, null given, called in /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 146

Any one faced similar issues after upgrade to 2.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:
For part 1: It was some configuration issue, so I downloaded the core_config_data table and replaced it with my staging site one

For part 2: Replaced vendor/Temando folder with 2.3.2 one

For part 3: I was using VladmirPopov webforms extension, it was causing the issue in cms pages, so downloaded the latest version webforms of extension and replaced it.